# How to express the line before the last in vim?

Tags: vim

How to  express the line before the last in vim?
It is clear that $ is the last line.If there is a article which contain 20 llines,$ is equal 20 here, how about the line before the last,it is 19 ,how to write it such as $-1 ,can we create a expression 19=$-1??

Comment: How do you want to use the expression for the last line number minus one?

Comment: `:echo line('$')-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference the last minus `n` line in command line you can use `$-n`.

For instance, to go to the second to last line:

```
:$-        # same as :$-1
```

You can use it to define a range:

```
:,$-10     # from the current line to 10 lines before the last one
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are asking.

A solution to reach the penultimate line is using something like :

```
:normal Gk
```

that you can map in a user defined command.